# Deploy maven site to subdirectory with mercurial?

Tags: java, mercurial, maven

Until I can come up with a solution to [deploying a Maven SNAPSHOT site to a different subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428439/create-and-deploy-a-maven-site-for-the-most-recent-snapshot), I'm now trying to deploy to a subdirectory based on the version number.

But it appears I can't do that either due to my deployment strategy: Pushing the site to a remote Mercurial repo that's hosted on Google Code (its free hosting, so why not)

My current configuration is this

```
<distributionManagement>
    <!--Site deploy repository-->
    <site>
        <id>MYPROJECT.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>scm:hg:https://code.google.com/p/MYPROJECT.site/${project.version}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

But when I run `mvn site:deploy`, it can't do the initial clone of the repository since Mercurial doesn't (yet) support partial clones of repositories. The real repo lives at `https://code.google.com/p/MYPROJECT.site/`

Is there any way to deploy the site into a subdirectory with Mercurial? Or am I asking way to much of Maven?